# JavaScript slideshow not working (images are static)

Tags: javascript

I am quite new to JavaScript and I am trying to implement a slider. Below is the javascript code that I am trying to solve.

```html
<html>
  <head> 
    <title> Home Page </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="w3.js">
      $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

      setInterval(function() {
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
          .fadeOut(1000)
          .next()
          .fadeIn(1000)
          .end()
          .appendTo('#slideshow');
      }, 3000);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="slideshow">
      <div>
        <img src="http://vectorlogofree.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/23656-apple-logo-icon-vector-icon-vector-eps.png">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/0/02/Linux_icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20141003183250&path-prefix=en">
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]
It is not working and the images are static. Any idea why? Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: Not working? What's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **jquery** in order to be able to use that plugin.

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <title>
      Home Page
    </title>
    <!-- here -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

      setInterval(function() {
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
          .fadeOut(1000)
          .next()
          .fadeIn(1000)
          .end()
          .appendTo('#slideshow');
      }, 3000);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="slideshow">
      <div>
        <img src="http://vectorlogofree.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/23656-apple-logo-icon-vector-icon-vector-eps.png">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/0/02/Linux_icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20141003183250&path-prefix=en">
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Check out the @Jiib answer to fix your style issue and you'll be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the the following css to your parent and child element, the problem with the positioning is fixed:

CSS:

```
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
}

#slideshow > div{
  position: absolute;
}
```

here is a demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/cjd5ja7d/2/

But have you considered to use an external jquery plugin for your slideshow?
here are some great examples:

- https://bxslider.com/ (easy to use)
- http://idangero.us/swiper/ (more
  advanced)